# Vuetify Data Tables using array of arrays as items

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

Below is the sample response from an API. How can use I [Vuetify Data Tables](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables) to render it.

Json:

```
{
    "records":[[101,"Aa"],[102,"Bb"],[103,"Cc"]],
    "column_names":["Id","Name"]
}
```

Table:

```
 Id  |  Name
- - - - - - -
 101 |  Aa
 102 |  Bb
 103 |  Cc
```

Key problem is that it don't have items as dictionary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For basic Vuetify data table, you need to define `headers` and `items` as empty arrays.

```js
data() {
  return {
    headers: [],
    items: []
  }
}
```

Then just fetch your `"column_names"` data to populate `headers` and `"records"` data to populate `items`
Something like:

```js
response['column_names'].forEach(resp => {
  this.headers.push({ text: resp, value: resp.toLowerCase() })
})
response['records'].forEach(resp => {
  this.items.push({ id: resp[0], name: resp[1] })
})
```

Items keys just need to match with the headers values (in your example : "id" and "name")

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is this efficient if I'm getting millions of records? Is there any way other way to implement without redecorating the data?

Comment: @bkmagnetron you can use pagination ([codepen example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LmMoLo?editors=1010)) if you have a lot of records

Comment: @Sovalina is there a way to do this while maintaining reactivity to the source data?

Answer (score 0):

for the html, map it to the item array by index?

```
<td>{{ props.item[0] }}</td>
<td>{{ props.item[1] }}</td>
```

the reason to use array of array is for performance, right? I dont think changing it to object is a proper solution.